# How do I send a message in a channal at a specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want my discord python bot to send a specific message in a channel 2 times a day. First at 12 o'clock and then 18 o'clock in Europe/Berlin time (or just from the server time).

How do I make it? I tried many things but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APScheduler` and `Cron` to schedule your messages to be sent at a specific time, like 12:00 AM

Docs: [`APScheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [`Cron`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html)

Here is an example:

```py
#async scheduler so it does not block other events
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

async def func():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    c = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await c.send("Your Message")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

    #initializing scheduler
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    #sends "Your Message" at 12PM and 18PM (Local Time)
    scheduler.add_job(func, CronTrigger(hour="12, 18", minute="0", second="0")) 

    #starting the scheduler
    scheduler.start()
```

Comment: I found a little caveat with this above piece of code, if the discord bot tries to reconnect after a network outage. It executes the `on_ready()` again causing to add the `func` job again. Thus adding the jobs as many times as there were network outages in a long running bot.

Comment: for that, you can use on_connect and on_disconnect, you can remove all jobs on_disconnect and register jobs on on_connect as on_ready can be called multiple time due to reasons

Comment: I just moved everything from `on_ready()` to outside, like initializing the scheduler and adding the jobs just below the command prefix setup and starting the scheduler just before the `bot.run('TOKEN')`. I hope that is okay and it will not cause any major issues.

Comment: yup that works too

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified version of `@Just for fun`'s answer. I carried `scheduler` under `task()` function that is called from `discord.loop.create_task()` and (I adjusted the cron entry).

---

##### Solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path

import discord
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from broker._utils.tools import get_dt_time
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# In case to disable logging
logging.getLogger("apscheduler.executors.default").propagate = False

class Discord_Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        dotenv_path = Path(".env_secret")
        load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
        self.channel_id = int(os.getenv("CHANNEL_ALPY"))
        try:
            self.client.loop.create_task(self.task())
            self.client.loop.run_until_complete(self.client.start(self.TOKEN))
        except SystemExit:
            pass
            # handle_exit()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # handle_exit()
            self.client.loop.close()
            print("Program ended")

    async def task(self):
        scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(self.send_message, "cron", hour="12")
        scheduler.add_job(self.send_message, "cron", hour="18")
        # For test purposes
        scheduler.add_job(self.send_message, "cron", minute="*")  
        scheduler.start()

    async def send_message(self, msg=""):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        channel = self.client.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        if not msg:
            msg = f"Tick! The time is: {get_dt_time().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}"

        await channel.send(msg)


_discord = Discord_Bot()
```

Example output:

```
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:445 -               add_job()] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:445 -               add_job()] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:445 -               add_job()] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:886 -         _real_add_job()] Added job "Discord_Bot.send_message" to job store "default"
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:886 -         _real_add_job()] Added job "Discord_Bot.send_message" to job store "default"
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:886 -         _real_add_job()] Added job "Discord_Bot.send_message" to job store "default"
[2021-08-01 14:52:40         base.py:171 -                 start()] Scheduler started
[2021-08-01 14:52:40       client.py:510 -                 login()] logging in using static token
[2021-08-01 14:52:42      gateway.py:403 -              identify()] Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
[2021-08-01 14:52:42      gateway.py:494 -      received_message()] Shard ID None has connected to Gateway: ["gateway-prd-main-jqb3",{"micros":37874,"calls":["discord-sessions-green-prd-2-83",{"micros":36893,"calls":["start_session",{"micros":33555,"calls":["api-prd-main-lx4l",{"micros":30479,"calls":["get_user",{"micros":2553},"add_authorized_ip",{"micros":2438},"get_guilds",{"micros":5864},"coros_wait",{"micros":1}]}]},"guilds_connect",{"micros":1,"calls":[]},"presence_connect",{"micros":2743,"calls":[]}]}]}] (Session ID: ff6cc313c16950abadccfab95a02d3a5).
[2021-08-01 14:53:00      base_py3.py:28 -     run_coroutine_job()] Running job "Discord_Bot.send_message (trigger: cron[minute='*'], next run at: 2021-08-01 14:54:00 UTC)" (scheduled at 2021-08-01 14:53:00+00:00)
[2021-08-01 14:53:00      base_py3.py:41 -     run_coroutine_job()] Job "Discord_Bot.send_message (trigger: cron[minute='*'], next run at: 2021-08-01 14:54:00 UTC)" executed successfully
```