# How do I emit custom discord.py events?

Tags: python, discord.py

In discord.py, I am able to use even listeners like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_event_name(*args, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
```

I have seen some libraries that appear to emit custom events, ones that aren't included in discord.py be default. I'm wondering how this is done? I'm looking for something like this:

```
# bot.py:
@bot.event
async def my_event_name(data):
    #do stuff

# somewhere else
await bot.emit('my_event_name', data)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460182/discord-py-how-to-invoke-another-command-inside-another-one

Comment: @kr8gz no, that's for invoking commands manually. I want to invoke custom events

Comment: You can just use functions for this.

Comment: @Cloud I could, but I'd rather use events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own events using `Bot.dispatch`

Here is an example:

```py
bot.dispatch("my_event", a, b, c)
```

is heard by

```py
a, b, c = await bot.wait_for("my_event")
```

and

```py
@bot.event
async def on_my_event(a, b, c):
  # ...
```

(don't forget to write the "on_" at the beginning of your function)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This is great, but I'm curious - what if you wanted to invoke your custom event either dynamically or on some sort of schedule? For example, at 6pm every day trigger a custom event. Or periodically check a database for new information (perhaps an entry in the "bot_message_queue" table), and trigger the event then?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is there some sort of event scheduler where you can tell your own events to fire off at intervals?

Comment: Look at this post and answer for a scheduler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491012/discord-py-send-channel-message-at-specific-time